# React Native error Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED after install React Drawer Navigation v6

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

i got my react native app error after i installed react-navigation-drawer. please help

comand: **npm run android**

```
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
7 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 5 up-to-date
[..................] / : timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[..................] / : timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: /home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: /home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

at makeError (/home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/home/risman/drive/android/project/POS/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

I followed how to install react-navigation-drawer on the official documentation on [installation guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#installation)